# Count User Registerd by day & month | Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I found this code and corrected it a bit. But it does not work properly. I want to count new users (daily and monthly) who join the site. For example :

new users today: 5
new users month: 30

Can anyone modify and test my code?

```html
$date = getdate();

$data_user_reg = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->users WHERE user_registered AND MONTH(user_registered)= $date[mday]");
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! _But it does not work properly_ - what does that mean? Are you getting an error? What results are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

```
getdate();
```

return

```
Array
(
   [seconds] => 31
   [minutes] => 6
   [hours] => 6
   [mday] => 3
   [wday] => 5
   [mon] => 6
   [year] => 2022
   [yday] => 153
   [weekday] => Friday
   [month] => June
   [0] => 1654236391
)
```

and you use

> mday

means day of month

for day base count query is

```
$date = getdate();

$data_user_reg = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->users WHERE user_registered AND DAY(user_registered)= $date[mday]");
```

for month base count use

> mon

and query is

```
$data_user_reg = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->users WHERE user_registered AND MONTH(user_registered)= $date[mon]");
```

Comment: but not worked.